# Select button from DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate without focusing grid

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

How can i select button without focusing item from a DataGrid:

[image: 1]

I try to select trash icon, but first click make select on grid:

[image: 2]

and second click can execute remove command.
I try something like this:

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

but i don't have desired result

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `IsHitTestVisible` property to false to ignore clicks to the `Cell`. Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.ishittestvisible?view=winrt-22621).

Comment: I don't want to ignore clicks, i want to select button with 1 click, IsHitTestVisible is not my solution.